# How to escape duplicated value from excel and try to insert into database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Dear Friend I creating Import feature in Codeigniter using below function but I don't know how to escape when duplicated value happen on my data when my loop selected from excel
The Primary key is only used for **$in_val['in_no']** and other value is free to insert.
**How to escape duplicated value and try to insert other row from excel into database?**

Here is my Function

```
public function imported($file_paths) {
        $in_val = array();
        $i = 0;
        $cell_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_paths);
        foreach ($cell_array as $row) {
            if ($i === 7000)break; {
                $in_val['user_id'] = 70;
                $in_val['in_no'] = (int) preg_replace("/(\D+\d{4})0*([1-9]+\d*)/i", "$2\n", trim($row['IN_number']));
                $in_val['fi_no'] = trim($row['Fir_obtic']);
                $in_val['paid_by'] = trim($row['Paid_by']);
                $in_val['in_per'] = str_replace('/', '-', trim($row['In_date']));
                $in_val['sale_by'] = trim($row['Sale_by']);
                $in_val['billed'] = trim($row['Billed']);
                $in_val['in_date'] = str_replace('/', '-', trim($row['In_date']));
                $in_val['top_up_num'] = trim($row['T_P_number']);
                $in_val['ffrom'] = trim(str_replace('/', '-', $row['From']));
                $in_val['fto'] = str_replace('/', '-', trim($row['to']));
                $in_val['pay_du_date'] = str_replace('/', '-', trim($row['Pay_due_date']));
                $in_val['bill_amount'] = trim(str_replace('/', '-', $row['Bill_Amount']));
                $in_val['bill_to'] = trim($row['Cust_name']); //customer name
                $in_val['receiv_date'] = trim($row['R_C_date']);
                $in_val['adds'] = trim($row['Address']);
                $in_val['bill_item'] = str_replace('/', '-', trim($row['Bill_Item']));
                $in_val['descr'] = trim($row['Description']);
                $in_val['in_type'] = strtolower(preg_replace("/(\D+\d{0})0*([0-9]+\d*)/i", "$1\n", trim($row['IN_number'])));
                $in_val['quant'] = trim($row['In_Quanity']);
                $in_val['unit_p'] = trim($row['In_Unit_P']);
                $in_val['amount'] = trim($row['Bill_Amount']);
                $in_val['total'] = trim($row['Total']);
                $in_val['status'] = 1;
                $in_val['amc'] = trim($row['Amount_Description']);
                $pri_val['user_id'] = 70;
                $pri_val['type'] = strtolower(preg_replace("/(\D+\d{4})0*([1-9]+\d*)/i", "$1\n", trim($row['IN_number'])));
                $pri_val['parent'] = 1;
                $pri_val['status'] = 1;
                $pri_val['in_no'] = (int) $in_val['in_no'];
                $pri_val['total'] = (int) trim($row['Total']);
                $pri_val['in_date'] = $in_val['in_date'];
                $this->db->insert('dbfinan_invoice', $in_val);
                $this->db->insert('prifix', $pri_val);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: How do you know it is a duplicate ? What seems to be the primary key `user_id` is always set to 70.

Comment: Sorry for my miss sentence. Because i make primary key for only  $in_val['in_no']

Comment: Means you want to avoid from inserting those set of data that primary key is same with one set that you inserted yeah? checking duplicate inside file data or with table data?

Comment: @MobasherFasihy
That is right

Answer (score 0):

try add condition and function to check in table like this:

```
if($this->[yourmodal]->isExist($in_val['in_no'])==false)
{
  $this->db->insert('dbfinan_invoice', $in_val);
  $this->db->insert('prifix', $pri_val);
}
```

So $in_val['in_no'] in table can unique

Comment: Is it be slow or not if I use this function to check rows on database and compare with more row i import from Excel because this is import feature

Comment: Yes. More data certainly make more process too. I think that the risk and not the best method

Comment: I'm too much difficult to make import from excel feature now because I have to escape duplicates on In_no value mean that if the have the same value in excel it will try to insert next row by throwing the duplicated row but i don't know how to do

Comment: I think with that condition enough